# Akka and Java libraries that use ThreadLocals

Tags: java, message-queue, akka, thread-local, thread-local-storage

What has kept me from using Akka regularly (in Java) is a concern I have with libraries that use ThreadLocals.

That is I *think* some Akka Dispatchers may cause ThreadLocal variables to be left behind, or missing all together. So the obvious solution would be to avoid using **ThreadLocals** but there are so many libraries that use them: Spring, Wro4j, Log4j, etc etc...

ThreadLocals normally work fine in Servlet Container. That is because even though containers have threadpools the request is mainly a synchronous lifecycle, thus generally at the end of a request things like Spring and Wro4J will clean up there threadlocals. Some containers like Tomcat even monitor threadlocal leaks.

Such is not the case in Akka from what I understand.

**How do people get around this issue?**

For now I just avoid using Akka and use a Message Queue (like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ) but would like to use Akka as it covers a wider range of async problem/solution.

I also think Netty has similar issues but I believe Netty offers some sort Channel Context object that you can use in place of ThreadLocal and in theory some libraries may know to use that instead of ThreadLocal.

Comment: What exactly are the concerns you have with ThreadLocals? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Lets say Spring binds a Transaction to a Thread because I did some sort of JDBC operation in an Actor then Akka essentially suspends that  thread and hands it off to a different actor... you might get some weird behavior... or worse maybe the transaction never closes. Another example is Log4J and logback's MDC: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/f5YDBKVExmQ/_mOOuQu2SXcJ

Comment: @AlexObjelean for Wro4j its lets of an issue because its in the Request Thread and I don't think you have it so that it inherits into other threads (although I did have some trouble trying to get your library to work with Netty I eventually just did the asset pipeline myself avoiding wro4j's context object).

Comment: I think you should not worry that much about ThreadLocal itself, rather than the sloppy usage of ThreadLocal: http://old.nabble.com/Threadlocals-and-memory-leaks-in-J2EE-td13097957.html#a13097957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve it is to demarcate the use of ThreadLocals, so you create a method as such:

```
def withSecurityContext[T](thunk: => T)(implicit secCtx: SecurityContextFetcher): T = {
  val old = threadLocalSecurityContext.get
  threadLocalSecurityContext.set(secCtx.fetch)
  try thunk finally threadLocalSecurityContext.set(old)
}
```

Then inside your Actor or whatnot:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case "foo" => withSecurityContext { beAwesome() }
    }
}
```

In general though, I'd avoid ThreadLocals because they don't really blend in with distributed systems. They only work in clearly demarcated sections.

Comment: do you think it would be worthwhile for Akka to support some ThreadLocal leak detection like Tomcat does (perhaps on shutdown of Akka)? Maybe a little side project (porting Tomcat's detection) that I could do that would help assuage my fears :)

Comment: Akka is open source, if you want to tackle this issue and submit a PullRequest I'll gladly consider including it!